# Retry async/await try and catch block three times before responding with an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

Found similar issues, but none of which answered my question. I need to try to run an async function three times before throwing an error. Currently doing it with a while loop doing, which doesn't feel right to begin with. It is all happening in an express route. This is what my code currently looks like:

```
const MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES = 3
router.post('/', async function (req, res) {
  let tries = 0
  while (true) {
    try {
      await myAsyncFunction(body)
      res.json({ success: true, message: 'Done!' })
    } catch (err) {
      if (tries >= MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: err && err.message })
      }
    }
    tries++
  }
}
```

One of the issues is that when I do this I always get the following error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

This does not appear without the loop.
So I suppose the question is, how do I limit these calls to three tries before responding with the error? Is this the correct path or is there another way to do it? And why am I getting issues with the headers?

Comment: When does the loop end? Hint: never.

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/retry.html
May be the `rxjs` `retry` operator will do for you

Comment: to handle the error, you must call the `catch` function next ot your async function --> `myAsyncFunction(body).catch(x => {});`

Comment: The error is about setting the `headers`, but your code is not related to the error.

Comment: @Sergej [Not necessary to catch it like that](https://medium.com/@pyrolistical/the-hard-error-handling-case-made-easy-with-async-await-597fd4b908b1), since myAsyncFunction is already awaited. Also, `res.json` sets content _and_ headers, which is why it causes the error if it's called twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return after `res.json({ success: false, message: err && err.message })` like this:

```js
...
res.json({ success: false, message: err && err.message })
return
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that `while` loop looks sketchy. You never stop it. Just use a normal loop instead. Also you will need to break when you got a response.

```
const MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES = 3
router.post('/', async function (req, res) {
  var message;
  for (let tries = 0; tries < MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES; tries++) {
    try {
      await myAsyncFunction(body)
      res.json({ success: true, message: 'Done!' })
      return
//    ^^^^^^
    } catch (err) {
      message = err && err.message;
      console.log(`Try ${tries}: ${err}`)
    }
  }
  res.json({ success: false, message })
}
```

---

An alternative to this little weird control flow is to use recursion, which is well suited for retrying:

```
async function getResult(body, retries) {
  try {
    await myAsyncFunction(body)
    return {success: true, message: 'Done'}
  } catch(err) {
    if (retries > 0)
      return getResult(body, retries-1)
    else
      return {success: false, message: err && err.message}
  }
}

const MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES = 3
router.post('/', async function (req, res) {
  const RETRIES = MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRIES - 1
  res.json(await getResult(body, RETRIES))
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the retry logic to the async function, something like the below
This just an example of how it can be achieved, adjust it to your need.

```
router.post('/', async function(req, res) {
  try {
    var result = await asyncFunc(3 /* retries */);
    res.send(result);
  } catch(ex)
  {
    res.send(ex);
  }
})
```

in your async function, you can implement something like

```
async asyncFunc(retries)
{
  for(var i = 0; i < retries; i++)
  {
    var result = await doSomething();
    if(result)
    {
      // break the loop
      return result;
    }
  }

   // if we land here, so the number of retries was exceeded
   throw Error("...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [async-retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-retry) package will do this for you; the amount of code actually ends up similar, but it's got a bit more capability and is less fiddly to get right.

For example:

```
const retry = require('async-retry')

try {
  await retry(async () => {
    await myAsyncFunction(body)
    res.json({ success: true, message: 'Done!' })
  }, {
    retries: 3,
  }) 
} catch (err) => 
{
   res.json({ success: false, message: err && err.message })
}
```

The outer catch handles the case where it retries three times and escapes the `retry` block. You can also set an `onError` function which has logic to be executed for each error (such as logging).